# Rails country select gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using country select gem and i want to search users based in their country for this i have tried this code but it seem that country_select_tag dosn't work so i am wondering what is the best way to do this job

```
<%= form_tag search_users_path, class:"form-wrapper_compdirect cf navbar-left", :method => :get do %>

   <%= country_select_tag :country, params[:country] %> 
   <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class:"quick-search_compdirect", placeholder:"Chercher des Utilisateurs" %> 
   <button type="submit" class="submit-button-search"><img src="/assets/search-g.png" title="Search" /></button>
<% end %>
```

and want also to know how to get the name of country and not the abbreviation in the show page for example i have in my show page this code

`Pays de l'utilisateur : <%= user.country %>`  but instead of getting France i get FR  do this job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUst use `<%= country_select :country, params[:country] %>` instead of `<%= country_select_tag :country, params[:country] %>`

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
country_select("user"#{model name}, "country"#{variable value})

country_select("user", params[:country])
```

and you can get country name using some method which has in the country_select documentation

check this link once: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/country_select/2.1.0/frames

Comment: in my application helper i have this code   def country_name
    country = ISO3166::Country[country_code]
    country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name
  end    and i my show page <%= user.country_name %> but i'm getting this error   undefined method `country_name'

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the first answer but because the form was shared and appeared on the results page, any subsequent form submit would break the query string.

```
<%= form_tag(search_path, method: :get) do %>
  <label for="country">Search by Country</label>
  <%= country_select nil, :country, { selected: params[:country] } %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

So now, if the form is shared it, will send the correct parameters back as well as update the field with the selected country.